# .NET 4.6.2 "Value cannot be null" exception at WebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

When I run the following code on .NET 4.6.2,

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "key=my real key is here");

string json = "{\r\n  \"to\": \"/topics/news\",\r\n  \"data\": {\r\n    \"item0\": \"0\",\r\n    \"item1\": \"1\"\r\n  }\r\n}";
var jsonbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

var reqStr = req.GetRequestStream();
reqStr.Write(jsonbytes, 0, jsonbytes.Length);
reqStr.Close();

var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Debug.WriteLine(res.StatusCode);
var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
Debug.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
```

the following exception occurs at `var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();`.

```
Exception   Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.dll ("Value cannot be null.")  System.ArgumentNullException
```

I could not get any more information. I do not know what value is null. I ran the same code on .NET 4.5.2, that exception did not occur. Why does this exception occur?

Comment: Use breakpoints to see what has got null.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown in this line and not in `var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());` ? `GetResponse` doesn't seem to throw argument null: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx while StreamReader ctor will if the stream is null https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please post the *full* exception, including the call stack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`. This will show where the exception was actually thrown

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The exception is thrown and catched in non-user code. TS only got a log entry. See Benlitz answer.

Comment: @adrianm handled exceptions do not appear in logs. The only way to get this is to break on all exceptions while debugging. It's even easier to find the call stack during debugging

Comment: Anyone experiencing this, they are patching it in `4.7`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This occurs because some code has been added in 4.6.2 that uses a try/catch to parse an enum from a string in your registry, that apparently most people don't have.

An issue on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1591948/httpwebrequest-getresponse-throws-argumentnullexception) has been opened for that, but as usual it will go nowhere and be closed as won't fix in 5 years.

I don't understand why they didn't use a TryParse. And I don't understand why they do so much exception-based code with such a poor support of exceptions in Visual Studio. Now I'm loosing 30s each time I start my project because I break at the beginning of my initialization - disabling ArgumentNullException is not an option for me, I want to break immediately if it happens in my application code.

I think in Visual Studio 2017 you will finally be able to disable exceptions per-assembly, so if this is bothering you too much feel free to download the preview.

Comment: When I first saw your answer, I misread the date of that issue as July 2016 (this year). Now, I saw it again, and it was July *2015*.  Probably, it will never be fixed and I would rather look for a workaround.

Comment: Incredibly, they are going to push a fix in `4.7`. See comment from David in the above link `"We have fixed this issue. The fix is already in .NET Framework 4.7. We now use .TryParse() instead of .Parse(). This avoids the exceptions being generated."`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure req.GetResponse() actually returns a value before you cast it to a HttpWebResponse - so first get the value, do a null check then cast if it has a value. With regards to .net 4.5.2, it depends what req.GetResponse() returns null or not when no response is received from the server. The implementation might be different in 4.6 than in 4.5.2

Bottom line is - don't cast a value if you are not sure if it has a value or not and step through your code using the debugger.

Comment: I 'love it' when software is not backwards compatible and breaks existing code (mine works on 4.5.2. but not on 4.6.1. ......)    If we had written such poor c-r-a-p at DEC when I was in software development there, we would have gone bust. (Oh! but we DID go bust!)

Answer (score 0):

WebRequest.Response was working perfectly for me until I installed `SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)`. So it looks like `SSMS` breaks it.

I changed my code to use a lower version of .Net and that resolved the issue.